# Trying to figure a math puzzle/equation for a surprise trip using the date

Tags: riddle, mathematics, number-sequence

I planning a surprise trip for my husband's 40th.  He is a math geek. I am not.  My plan is to tell him in a series of riddles/puzzles that he needs to figure out. We are going to LA to see his favourite singer.  Anyway we are going Oct 25/6 (haven't 100% settled on the date) to Oct 30, 2019.  So I was thinking a math equation or puzzle or riddle to figure out the dates would work......but need help so please help

Comment: This question isn't on-topic for this site. Puzzle construction requests are off-topic (see [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5658/would-puzzle-construction-challenge-questions-be-off-topic-for-this-site)) and questions that request a compilation of puzzles that fit a criteria are also off-topic. It might be better if you ask this question on [meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/). You could also ask for help in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair)!

Comment: My bad, I overlooked the fact that you're after a series of puzzles, not just one.

Comment: Look at some existing puzzles and copy what you like.